# how to disable kendo ui dropdown list with jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

[image: Here is the render html code from browser]I am using kendo UI dropdownlist, I am new to kendo UI. I want to disable the dropdownlist if @TrackingHelper.CurrentUser.IsViewTestCallType return False.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(i => i.CallTypeId)

                                                    .Name("CallTypeId")
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                                                    .DataTextField("MasterValueName")
                                                    .DataValueField("MasterValueId")
                                                    .Events(x => x.Open("ManageSecurity"))
                                                    .DataSource(source =>
                                                    {
                                                        source.Read(read =>
                                                        {

                                                            read.Action("GetCallType", "Common", new { Area = "" });

                                                        });
                                                    })
                                                    .OptionLabel("Select Call Type")
                                            )
```

I am doing this in jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        debugger;
        var result = '@TrackingHelper.CurrentUser.IsViewTestCallType';
        if (result == "False")
        {
            $("#CallTypeId").prop("disabled", true);

        }

    });
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what's problem? code is not working?

Comment: I have posted this for fun ;), man its not working that's why the question is here

Comment: have you checked in debug what's going on? Wild gess: chenge your if to `if (result == "False" || result == "false" || result == false)`

Comment: yes I have checked the value of result is "False"

Comment: also  `$("#CallTypeId").prop('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: Yes I have tried it too, but not working :(

Comment: Please add it as answer so I can mark it, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use enable method of the widget.

```
$("#CallTypeId").data("kendoDropDownList").enable(false);
```

Comment: I was trying it this way var drp= $("#CallTypeId").data("kendoDropDownList");
           drp.options.enabled = false; Thanks man for your help, you have saved my lots of time. god bless you @uygar donduran

Answer (score 1):

After comments i can say that you just don't get your `select`. you should select it like this in your case i suppose:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        debugger;
        var result = '@TrackingHelper.CurrentUser.IsViewTestCallType';
        if (result == "False")
        {
            $("select[name=CallTypeId]").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
```

If you want to use `id` selector like you do already you should check what id generete your `Kendo().DropDownListFor`

Comment: I have tested the selector, its fine, and also tried your suggestion, but its still not working :(

Comment: I have added screen shot of rendered html in my question

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$("input[id=dropdownId]").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```